# Laravel : How can we create background thread

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-5.3

I am developing the portal, in which I required to check for the notification silently. So when-ever any notification received, notification count will update without refreshing or reloading page.

I used the queue concept but its not worked.

Can anyone help me for this challenge.

Comment: Is your question solved now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a connection through [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications).

Laravel has already implemented this. It is called [Event Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting) and works like a charm with Redis, Pusher or Sockets.IO. Give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Laravel Event Broadcasting with socket.io . I have tested and it worked prefectly . A how to : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51